# jQuery Selectors Removing table rows that meet two conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, html-table, conditional-statements

I'm trying to understand what techniques are employed when you have an operation that only runs when multiple conditions are met in jQuery. I don't know if a filter is the answer or not.

In my example, I have multiple tables on a page. I want to remove the rows of the table that meet two conditions. The first condition is that the row must not be the first row of the table (first child of the table element). The second condition is the row must not have any styling applied to it (no style element declared). I'm confused on the notation for a complex selector. I'm trying to go beyond the simple selectors now.

In my example, the table to use is labeled gvBigTable. I have the following:

```
$("#gvBigTable table tbody tr.not('style')").remove();
$("#gvBigTable table tbody tr.not(first-child)".remove();
```

I want to combine these conditions so that both must be met in order for the row to be removed. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You could satisfy those rules with one selector (and almost implement the requirement in pure CSS, if you accept `display: none` in place of `.remove()`): `#gvBigTable table tbody tr:first-child ~ tr:not([style]) { display: none; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not used `:not()` correctly. You can do it like following.

```js
$("table tbody tr:not(':first-child'):not('[style]')").remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>111</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>222</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="">
            <td>333</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>444</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**UPDATE:** according to the suggestion of [David Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82548/david-thomas) a pure CSS solution is like following.

```css
table tbody tr:first-child ~ tr:not([style]) { 
    display: none; 
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>111</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>222</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="">
      <td>333</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>444</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If you don't want to use `display: none` then you can use the selector `table tbody tr:first-child ~ tr:not([style])` with jQuery to remove the rows.

Comment: Thank you. So the way I read this statement, the chaining of the selectors acts like an AND statement. How does this logic change if I wanted an OR statement? Do I place a comma in between the conditions?

Comment: Yes place comma like `$("table tbody tr:not(':first-child'), table tbody tr:not('[style]')")`. @captainduh

Comment: It's not really worth adding another answer to the question, would you mind having a read of my [comment to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40028545/jquery-selectors-removing-table-rows-that-meet-two-conditions#comment67335435_40028545) and updating your answer?

Comment: Many thanks, I got back to a computer and added a snippet as a proof-of-concept to your answer also. :) I realise it's your answer, but the deletion of the CSS from the Snippet makes the Snippet non-functional, so you might want to remove the whole thing if its addition offended you?

Comment: Nothing offended me. That was my mistake. The CSS were added twice, once in snippet & other out side of snippet. I mistakenly deleted the snippet's CSS instead of other. @DavidThomas